# Compiling CodeMirror input

Tags: javascript, css, html, codemirror

I'm trying to figure out how to compile CodeMirror input in a text area and display it. I've searched for what feels like forever and even went through the entire source code to try and find something of use. The only thing I've found was a `.getValue()` method. Is this what i would use and how would it be applied? It doesn't seem like there exists even a single example of this online or in the docs. I implemented my CodeMirror instance in a seperate `.js` file as follows

```
function codeMirrorInstance(){
    var editableCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('editable_area'), {
    mode: "htmlmixed",
    theme: "default",
    lineNumbers: true
    });
};
```

From this point im basically just trying to figure out anyway to take the current input or code that the user types into the instance and have them hit a button to compile it and show the result.

Comment: `getValue` gives you the code. How you compile it is a question that CodeMirror has absolutely nothing to do with (which explains why the CodeMirror docs don't talk about it)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was sort of leaning towards at this point. I have never worked with an embedded code editor before so i apologize and thanks for the comment.